# Junit testing - Initialization Exception error

Tags: java, junit, mockito, easymock, powermock

```
//registry Class
public class Registry
{

   private static final Logger logger = LogFactory
         .getLogger(Registry.class);

   protected Service service = new serviceMLImpl();
   private static Registry instance = new Registry();

   public static Registry getInstance()
   {
      return instance;
   }

   public static void setInstance(Registry instance)
   {
      Registry.instance = instance;
   }

   public Helper getHelper()
   {
      return new Helper();
   }


}


//Helper Class
public class Helper
{

   protected Service  service = ServiceRegistry
       .getService();

   public Helper()
   {
   }

   public void sendInfo(Info info)
       throws Exception
   {
      service.sendInfo(info);

   }

   public void sendFacilitySFPListNotification(
       List<GcpFacilitySFPInfo> esfpPortList)
   {
      gfpGcpService.sendFacilitySFPListNotification(esfpPortList);
   }

}

//Test Class

public class RegistryTest
{

   Registry registry = new Registry();
   Helper helper = createMock(Helper.class);

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception
   {

   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() throws Exception
   {
      registry = null;
   }

   @Test
   public void testGetInstance()
   {
      replayAll();
      registry.getInstance();
      verifyAll();
   }

   @Test
   public void testSetInstance()
   {
      replayAll();
      registry.setInstance(registry);
      verifyAll();
   }

   @Test
   public void testGetHelper()
   {
      **replayAll();
      new Helper();
      registry.getHelper(); // getting InitializationExceptionError here
      verifyAll();**              //
   }

}
```

Two classes are there, **Helper** and **Registry** class. I tried to write the junit for registry class but got *InitializationException* in the test class.

This is the error i am getting at registry.getHelper():

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) at
javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:44) at
javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:153) at
javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:123) at
javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:79) at
com.att.bbnms.cim.gfpgcp.service.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java‌​:41) at
com.att.bbnms.cim.nc.service.link.Helper.(Helper.java:14) at
com.att.bbnms.cim.nc.service.link.Registry.getHelper(Registry.java:26) at
com.att.bbnms.cim.nc.service.link.egistryTest.testGetHelper(RegistryTest.java:63‌​) at
org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66) at
org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$Po‌​werMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:‌​312) at
org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86) at
org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadi‌​e.java:94) at
org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$Po‌​werMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:29‌​6) at
```

Also while writing the test case for **Helper** , I am not able to get in the class. 
Please tell if you have any solution.

Comment: What is the complete Exception ? There must be a message appended with the Exception

Comment: Wheres the ServiceRegistry class, its the missing piece of the puzzle

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:44) at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:153) at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:123) atj avassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:79) at

Comment: com.att.bbnms.cim.gfpgcp.service.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:41) at com.att.bbnms.cim.nc.service.link.Helper.(Helper.java:14) at com.att.bbnms.cim.nc.service.link.Registry.getHelper(Registry.java:26) at com.att.bbnms.cim.nc.service.link.egistryTest.testGetHelper(RegistryTest.java:63) at

Comment: org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312) at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86) at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296) at

Comment: This is the error i am getting at  registry.getHelper();

Comment: 1st why do you write such hard to test code? Why there is in Registry class  method getHelper() that returns new instance of another class that use static factory to get a service? Maybe would be good to try refactor the code and everything would be more easier. Good luck

Comment: The error you have is at `com.att.bbnms.cim.gfpgcp.service.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java‌​:41)` and you haven't included any code for the ServiceRegistry class.